# Communicating between vue component and vue instance

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

I have just started using Vue.js and after trying for quite some time I can't figure out how to communicate something from a component to the vue instance.
I am using this component as a rating system but I don't understand how to get the current value to my main instance
( https://fiddle.jshell.net/swyuarc9/ )

```
Vue.component('star-rating', {

  props: {
    'name': String,
    'value': null,
    'id': String,
    'disabled': Boolean,
    'required': Boolean
  },

  template: '<div class="star-rating">\
        <label class="star-rating__star" v-for="rating in ratings" \
        :class="{\'is-selected\': ((value >= rating) && value != null), \'is-disabled\': disabled}" \
        v-on:click="set(rating)" v-on:mouseover="star_over(rating)" v-on:mouseout="star_out">\
        <input class="star-rating star-rating__checkbox" type="radio" :value="rating" :name="name" \
        v-model="value" :disabled="disabled">★</label></div>',

  /*
   * Initial state of the component's data.
   */
  data: function() {
    return {
      temp_value: null,
      ratings: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
    };
  },

  methods: {
    /*
     * Behaviour of the stars on mouseover.
     */
    star_over: function(index) {
      var self = this;

      if (!this.disabled) {
        this.temp_value = this.value;
        return this.value = index;
      }

    },

    /*
     * Behaviour of the stars on mouseout.
     */
    star_out: function() {
      var self = this;

      if (!this.disabled) {
        return this.value = this.temp_value;
      }
    },

    /*
     * Set the rating of the score
     */
    set: function(value) {
      var self = this;

      if (!this.disabled) {
        // Make some call to a Laravel API using Vue.Resource

        this.temp_value = value;
        return this.value = value;
      }
    }
  }

});

new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Welcome to Vue!

It might be a bit harder at first, but the way you pass down properties are via `props`. To do that, you need to first define a `data` object on your parent (in this case, your app instance).

There are some good examples on props in the [vue-docs](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components.html#Passing-Data-with-Props).
In general, this is how you do it:

```
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data: function () {
     return {
        foo: 'Foo'
     }
  }
});

Vue.component('bar', {
  props: { foo: String },
  template: '<span> {{ foo }}</span>'
})
```

...and the HTML

```
<div id="app">
  <bar :foo="foo"></bar<
</div>
```

I forked your fiddle and added a demo prop, just so you see it in action.
[Check it out](https://fiddle.jshell.net/e6oyo4dL/1/).

Comment: Are you sure the one you linked is working? Nothing happens if I hover the mouse on the stars.

Comment: I didn't go ahead and implement your solution (not even sure how it should work exactly), I just added an example to it showing how to share data between comps. It's up to you to implement the correct behavior :-)

Comment: I was able to fix it by using emit/on. I think your solution is more suitable if you want to communicate something to a child node. Having said that, thanks for the help :)

Comment: No worries, good luck! Be careful with events, if you have too many it's going to become very difficult to maintain your code later on :-)